# Dimension of vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$be the vectorspace of all polynomials. And $W$ is the subspace spanned by $t^2+t+2, t^2+2t+5, 5t^2+3t+4,2t^2+2t+4$. 
The question asks us to find the dimension of $W$. Here is my try:
Let us call the four polynomials as  $A$,$B$,$C$&$D$ in the order as they appear in the question. Then a cursory look at the four polynomials shows that $A$and $D$ are linearly dependent. So one of them could be removed and we could proceed with remaining $3$. I removed $D$.
 Next when I formed a $3\times3$ matrix having coefficients of $t^2,t$ and constant terms in  $A$,$B$&$C$  as its rows, I found the three polynomials to be linearly dependent. $C$ could be written as a linear combination of $A$ and $B$. So I concluded that $W$ could be spanned by $A$ and $B$.
 But what about the dimension of $W$? How to find that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $A(t)$ cannot be a multiple of $B(t)$ implies that you need at least 2 polynomials to span $W$. So, the dimension = the minimum number of spanning elements = 2.

Easy way to check: find the rank of the matrix formed by the coefficients of the polynomials (THINK WHY!):
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2\\
1&2&5\\
5&3&4\\
2&2&4
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Rank of this matrix will tell how many of 4 polynomials are linearly independent and required to span $W$ as the polynomials corresponding to zero rows in the echelon form can be safely removed from the basis of $W$.

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT No! Row-reduction doesn’t preserve dependency relations among the rows. You can find a basis for $W$ and thus its dimension by reducing to echelon form, but that tells you nothing about the dependencies among the original rows. Try a simple counterexample such as $\small{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}}$. However, if you start with the vectors as _columns_ instead, then the original columns of this matrix that correspond to columns with no pivots in the resulting echelon form can be safely removed.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension is at most $3$, since $W\subset P_2$.  It is at least $2$, as the first two are not multiples of each other.   The last is twice the first,  so can be thrown out.

Let's check if the first three are independent, by computing the following determinant:   $\begin{vmatrix}1&1&2\\1&2&5\\5&3&4\end{vmatrix}=1\cdot(8-15)-1\cdot (4-25)+2((3-10)=-7+21-14=0$.

Thus the first three are indeed dependent.

Thus $\operatorname {dim}W=2$.